# How do I get the base model object for serialization?

Tags: c#, object, radix

I have 2 model objects:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
public class SettingItem : Setting
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I do a Get from the server I get the SettingItem (with the description) which I use to bind to the UI.  On a save I want to serialize the Setting (Without the description) to return to the server.  To accomplish this I'm trying to create a new object of type Setting and populate it with the data from SettingItem, but my new object is not of type Setting, it's SettingItem:

```
        IEnumerable<Setting> settings = new List<Setting>(_settingItems);
```

The only thing I have been able to do is this conversion, which defeats the intention of the inheritance:

```
        var settings = _settingItems.Select(n => new NotificationSettingInput()
        {
            NotifyTypeId = n.NotifyTypeId,
            IsOptedIn = n.IsOptedIn
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a derived type to a base type permanently - that's entirely deliberate, as that's what polymorphism and inheritance is all about. Suppose you have a derived class which has overridden methods or enforced certain conditions on the arguments you set.

Provided you can't combine the classes and use `[NonSerialized]` as already suggested, The correct way to accomplish this is to initialize the base type and copy over the values just as you did. (a deep copy) Another way I could think of, is a custom serialization implementation, or modifying the serialized data afterwards.

For instance, within my company, we have a serialization class that takes the following: 
 `var xml = _serializer.Serialize<Setting>(settingItem);` 
 so it would only serialize the class as a `Setting` type. Not sure if the constructs in .Net support this.

**EDIT** Just looked, you can do this depending on the serialization method you choose. For instance, with the XmlSerializer:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
x.Serialize(Console.Out, settingsItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

This model is simple enough that you might not have to deal with inheritance. You can tag `Description` with a `NonSerialized` attribute, assuming we're not missing anything about how you actually perform the serialization.

```
public class Setting
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that the Setting class is shared between the client and the server with a common library, and since the server requires the ability to pass Description to the client, this wont work.